# Why does my well defined linear transformation not work?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following basis: { x, 1}. Using this basis, I define the following linear transformation:

$$S: \mathbb{R}_1[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_2[x]$$
$$S(x) = x^2\\S(1) = 0$$

I have a theorem which says that if a linear transformation is defined for each element of its basis, then it is well defined. However:

$$S(-x) = x^2 \neq-S(x) = -x^2$$

This contradicts the theorem, because the transformation as I have defined it does not allow for $S(-x) = -S(x)$. Why?

Comment: Examine why you think that $S(-x)=x^2$

Comment: @MatthewTowers I see. We simply attach the coefficient of $x$ to that of $x^2$, and not raise it by a power. Is this the proper syntax for it? Because it opens a door to confusion.

Comment: @daedsidog: $S$ extends _linearly_ from its partial definition on the basis elements, so $S(ax+b)=a{\,\cdot\,}S(x)+b{\,\cdot\,}S(1)=a{\,\cdot\,}x^2+b{\,\cdot\,}0=ax^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation here is strongly suggestive of, unfortunately, the wrong thing: that $S$ is an operator which takes in an arbitrary term and outputs the square of that term.

By changing notation it's easier to see what's going on. We have two basis elements $v_1,v_2$, and a function defined on this basis by $f(v_1)=w_1$ and $f(v_2)=w_2$.

Now we ask what $f(-v_2)$ - or rather, $\hat{f}(-v_2)$, where $\hat{f}$ is the extension of $f$ to all of our space *(note that you have a common minor abuse of notation, using $S$ to denote both the function defined on the basis elements only and the extension of that function to the whole space)* - is equal to. We need to write $-v_2$ as a linear combination of basis elements, and we do this as $$-v_2=0\cdot v_1 + (-1)\cdot v_2.$$ We now apply $f$ to each of the basis vectors in this expression and look at what we get: $$\hat{f}(-v_2)=0\cdot f(v_1)+(-1)\cdot f(v_2).$$ This is just $-f(v_2)$ - and shifting back to our original context, this gives the desired result that $S(-x)$ does indeed equal $-S(x)$.